# Visual Studio 2015 error "This interface is not supported (Exception of HRESULT : 0x800004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have this error when trying to create a new project on a freshly installed Visual Studio 2015 (Entreprise version on windows 10 x86_64). I've tried to unistall (using the [VisualStudioUnistaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller)) then reinstall the IDE several times but I get the same problem.

I'm suspecting a lack of some dependencies used by the IDE but I'm not sure about it. Here is a screen of some dependecies I've on my system :

[image]

Any ideas ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of project are you trying to create? Write or better post screenshot

Comment: @AlexejSommer an ASP MVC project. Here is a [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/DsUPzjS.png)

Comment: [and got this](http://i.imgur.com/NQ9TSvm.png) just after the installation is finished I checked and I found that I have a more recent version of MS Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable

Comment: Looks like you have some installation issue. There might be different C++ packages on the same machine. So, if Visual Studio asks for some special version, I think you should install it also.